# Starting with a list of initials and last names, extract full names from string of names

Tags: python, python-3.x

Starting with the following list of initials and last names:

```
['Arnold-Ker L.', 'Dutra Da Silva R.', 'Bracciali D.', 'Dlouhy L.']
```

I need to extract the full names from the following string:

```
arnold-ker-lucas-dutra-da-silva-rogerio-bracciali-daniele-dlouhy-lukas
```

The following function:

```
def get_full_names(player_name_str: str, short_names: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    player_names_split = player_name_str.split("-")

    full_names = list()

    for short_name in short_names:
        full_name = list()
        single_names = short_name.replace("-", " ").lower().split(" ")
        for single_name in single_names:
            try:
                initial = re.search(r"^(\w)\.$", single_name).group(1)
            except AttributeError:
                for idx, pn in enumerate(player_names_split):
                    if pn == single_name:
                        full_name.append(player_names_split[idx])
                        player_names_split = player_names_split[idx + 1 :]
                        break
            else:
                for idx, pn in enumerate(player_names_split):
                    if pn.startswith(initial):
                        full_name.append(player_names_split[idx])
                        player_names_split = player_names_split[idx + 1 :]
                        break

        full_names.append(" ".join(full_name))

    return full_names
```

Gives the desired output:

```
['arnold ker lucas', 'dutra da silva rogerio', 'bracciali daniele', 'dlouhy lukas']
```

However, initials and names are sometimes not quite correctly sequenced. I've amended the second item in the following list to simulate an example:

```
['Arnold-Ker L.', 'Silva D. R.', 'Bracciali D.', 'Dlouhy L.']
```

This outputs:

```
['arnold ker lucas', 'silva daniele', 'dlouhy', 'lukas']
```

I need to develop something more flexible, potentially with fuzzy matching. However, I'm going round in circles trying to figure out how to set where one name ends and another one starts.

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Some additional notes based on comments:

1. I need to extract the full names from the string, not expand the initials from the list.
2. There will always be 4 names in the list and the string
3. The order of names in the string will always be the same order as the list of names with initials.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally this is a diff problem (though not a line-by-line diff as we usually think about it). And that means that your current implementation, whereas it's "kind-of sometimes correct", doesn't do well in more difficult cases as you've found.

I don't recommend baking `AttributeError` into your logic, either.

Just delegate the works to the built-in [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html):

```py
import dataclasses
import difflib
import re
from typing import Sequence


@dataclasses.dataclass(slots=True)
class Name:
    short_fragments: list[str] = dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)
    long_fragments: list[str] = dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)

    def append(self, short: str, long: str) -> None:
        self.short_fragments.append(short)
        self.long_fragments.append(long)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return ' '.join(self.long_fragments)


def get_full_names(player_name_str: str, short_names: Sequence[str]) -> list[Name]:
    name_pat = re.compile(r'(?i)\w+')
    names = [Name() for _ in short_names]

    a = player_name_str.split("-")
    b_with_index = [
        (i, fragment)
        for i, short_name in enumerate(short_names)
        for fragment in name_pat.findall(short_name)
    ]
    b = [fragment.lower() for i, fragment in b_with_index]

    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b)
    for tag, a_lo, a_hi, b_lo, b_hi in matcher.get_opcodes():
        if tag in {'replace', 'equal'}:
            for long, (name_index, short) in zip(
                a[a_lo: a_hi],
                b_with_index[b_lo: b_hi],
            ):
                if tag == 'equal':
                    # Trust capitalisation of the short form
                    long = short
                else:
                    long = long.title()
                names[name_index].append(short, long)

    return names


def demo() -> None:
    for short_names in (
        ('Arnold-Ker L.', 'Dutra Da Silva R.', 'Bracciali D.', 'Dlouhy L.'),
        ('Arnold-Ker L.', 'Silva D. R.', 'Bracciali D.', 'Dlouhy L.'),
    ):
        for name in get_full_names(
            player_name_str='arnold-ker-lucas-dutra-da-silva-rogerio-bracciali-daniele-dlouhy-lukas',
            short_names=short_names,
        ):
            print(name)
        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()
```

```
Arnold Ker Lucas
Dutra Da Silva Rogerio
Bracciali Daniele
Dlouhy Lukas

Arnold Ker Lucas
Silva Rogerio
Bracciali Daniele
Dlouhy Lukas
```

Comment: This is fantastic thanks :) The challenge is that it misses off the "Dutra" in the second version of `short_names`. I could do without the "Da" but the "Dutra" is key for the next step in the process (not specified in my question)

Comment: This is about the best that the built-in algorithm can do. For element transposition you're going to need to look at a third-party library.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what your true objective is, here. Are you looking to partition the longer string into names, or looking to expand the initials in the shorter strings? Also, are you allowed to reject any of your inputs?

I would not consider it horrible if you were to reject `Silva D. R.` as an invalid match. (Unless your result requires a valid partition of the longer string, or something.)

Another element you have not discussed is ordering. Is it significant? Is it reliable? Will the initial-ised names always appear in the same relative order in the longer string?

If you are guaranteed that (1) every short name appears distinctly in the longer string; and (2) there are no overlaps; then you can use the more basic elements to partition the longer string into shorter parts. Eventually, you will have the worst-case elements (like 'Silva D. R.') unmatched, and some remaining elements of the long string. You can then score those elements based on the number of potential matches ('Silva' and 'word-starting-with-D' = 2) and give a best-guess.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've clarified your questions at the end of my post. Before I posted I too had been thinking about matching 'simple' names first but I started to go round in circles around how to keep track of which name I had matched as the output list needs to be in the same sequence as the input list...